# How scalar field couples to the $B$-field in Dilaton-Gravity-Maxwell action?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, interactions, effective-field-theory

Given the following $d$ dimensional dilaton-gravity-Maxwell low-energy effective action in the target space of a bosonic string:

$$S=\frac{1}{2\kappa^2}\int d^dx\sqrt{-G}e^{-2\Phi}\left[R-\frac{1}{12}g^{\alpha\beta}g^{\mu\gamma}g^{\nu \delta}H_{\alpha\mu\nu}H_{\beta \gamma \delta}+4g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \Phi \partial_{\nu}\Phi \right] $$
Where $H$ is written in terms of the $B$ field:

$$H_{\alpha\mu\nu}=\partial_{\alpha}B_{\mu\nu}+\partial_{\mu}B_{\nu\alpha}+\partial_{\nu}B_{\alpha\mu}.$$

Now, I want to add to this system a massive complex scalar field $\chi$ with a mass $m$ the new action would be:
$$S=\int d^dx\sqrt{-G}e^{-2\Phi}\left[\frac{1}{2\kappa^2}\left(R-\frac{1}{12}g^{\alpha\beta}g^{\mu\gamma}g^{\nu \delta}H_{\alpha\mu\nu}H_{\beta \gamma \delta}+4g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu} \Phi \partial_{\nu}\Phi\right) -g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\chi\partial_{\nu}\chi^* +m^2 \chi\chi^* \right] $$

Now suppose that $\chi $ is charged under the $B$ field, how does this would be manifested in the action?

In QFT I know that action (in flat spacetime) with a scalar field and an abelian gauge field $A$ which is given by the action
$$S=\int d^dx \left[ \partial_\mu\chi\partial^\mu\chi^* - m^2\chi\chi^*-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} \right]$$
can describe $\chi$ as a charged particle when considering a replacement of $\partial_\mu$ with a covariant derivative $D_\mu=\partial_\mu-iqA_\mu$ yielding after opening everything
$$S=\int d^dx \left[ \partial_\mu\chi\partial^\mu\chi^* +iq\left(\chi^* A^\mu\partial_\mu\chi-\chi A_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\chi^* \right) -q^2A_\mu A^\mu\chi\chi^* - m^2\chi\chi^*-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu} \right].$$

What is the corresponding covariant derivative now with the $B$-field?
The problem is that $B_{\mu\nu}$ have two indices so it is not possible to contract it with a single $\partial_\mu \chi$.